# Pivot to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, request, pivot

I have a query for 1 column AFFECTED_ITEM to 3 tables.

How can I do the same query for 2 columns AFFECTED_ITEM and ASSIGN?

This is a query for 1 column AFFECTED_ITEM to 3 tables

```
SELECT
 AFFECTED_ITEM,
   Table1,
   Table2,
   Table3

FROM (
SELECT  'Table1' as Tab, AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*) as AFFECTED_ITEMS from [dbo].[CM3RM1] WHERE ORIG_DATE_ENTERED between (@StartDate) and @EndDate + 1
and [AFFECTED_ITEM] in (@Affected_Item) and [COMPANY] in (@Company) and [ASSIGNED_TO] in (@Assignee) group by AFFECTED_ITEM
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Table2' as Tab, AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*) as AFFECTED_ITEMS from [dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]  WHERE  OPEN_TIME between (@StartDate) and @EndDate + 1
and [AFFECTED_ITEM] in (@Affected_Item) and [COMPANY] in (@Company) and [ASSIGNEE] in (@Assignee) group by AFFECTED_ITEM
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Table3' as Tab, AFFECTED_ITEM, Count(*) as AFFECTED_ITEMS from [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] WHERE  OPEN_TIME between @StartDate and @EndDate + 1
and [AFFECTED_ITEM] in (@Affected_Item) and [COMPANY] in (@Company)and  [ASSIGNEE_NAME] in (@Assignee) and [DDC_RESP_COMPANY] in (@Resp_Company) group by AFFECTED_ITEM
 ) t
PIVOT (SUM(AFFECTED_ITEMS) FOR Tab IN (Table1,Table2,Table3)
)as p
```

Comment: Is that query the one for "1 column AFFECTED_ITEM to 3 tables", or your attempted query for "same request for 2 columns AFFECTED_ITEM AND ASSIGN"?

Comment: This is a query for 1 column AFFECTED_ITEM to 3 tables

Comment: Your `IN` isn't doing what you think it does.